# mysqli : bind param where search parameters are conditional

Tags: php, mysqli

I would need a good structure for building queries where search parameters are conditional using **mysqli prepared statement**. `$query -> bind_param('sss',$date,$time,$place);`

I dont know how to apply `'sss'` and `'$date,$time,$place'` parameters in order later. Can you pass them as variable?

**Old MySQL way:**

```
<?php

// date is obligatory

$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["date"]);

$query="SELECT * FROM dbase WHERE date='$date'"; 

// time field is custom

if(!empty($_GET["time"])) {

    $time= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["time"]);
    $buildQuery[] = "time='$time'";

}

// place field is also custom

if(!empty($_GET["place"])) {

    $place= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["place"]);
    $buildQuery[] = "place='$place'";

}

// building query

if(!empty($build)) {

    $query .= ' AND '.implode(' AND ',$build).' ORDER BY date';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested, but you should be able to do something like this

```
$types = array();
$vals = array();

if(isset($_GET["time"])) {
    $types[] = 's';
    $vals[] = $_GET["time"];
    $buildQuery[] = "sType = ?";
}

//...etc...

$args = array_merge(array(join($types)), $vals);
$callable = array($mysqli, 'bind_param');
call_user_func_array($callable, $args));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

but, there's another approach. Just use logic in the sql:

```
select *
from tbl
where (date = ? or ? = '')
  and (time = ? or ? = '')
  and (place = ? or ? = '')
```

The above assumes you'll bind each arg twice, and bind them as strings, but binding an empty string if the query string param wasnt set... You could bind them as null if needed too via something like `(date = ? or ? is null)`.

```
$mysqli->bind_param('ssssss', $date,$date, $time,$time, $place,$place);
```

ps, the mysql optimizer will make short work of that simple logic.

Comment: How do you use the first example?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case where PDO is far easier than MySQLi:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM dbase";
$terms = array("date" => $date);
$params = array();

// time field is custom

if(isset($_GET["time"])) {
    $terms["sType"] = $time;
}

// place field is also custom

if(isset($_GET["place"])) {
    $terms["place"] = $place;  
}

// building query

if(!empty($terms)) {
    $query .= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", 
        array_map(function($term) { return "$term = ?"; }, array_keys($terms));
    $params = array_values($terms);
}
$query .= "ORDER BY date";

$stmt = $pdo->pepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

PS: I have to question whether you meant to have your `sType` column contain both *time* and *place*.  Seems like you're breaking relational database best practices.  Unless it's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Based on goat's reply, here's a full and tested answer with an UPDATE statement where the fields to be updated are conditional. I have used a very simple table structure with 3 fields: ID (auto increment), Varchar1 (varchar255) and Varchar2 (varchar255). In this script, I want to update the two varchar fields for the first three records. Based on this script, it's very easy to conditionally add or remove fields to be updated.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);

$types = array();
$vals = array();
$query = array();

// varchar1
$types[] = 's';
$vals[] = 'foo1';
$query[] = "varchar1=?";

// varchar2
$types[] = 's';
$vals[] = 'foo2';
$query[] = "varchar2=?";

$sql = "UPDATE test SET ".implode(",", $query)." WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

$args = array_merge(array(implode($types)), $vals);

$callable = array($stmt, 'bind_param');
call_user_func_array($callable, refValues($args));

$stmt->execute();

function refValues($arr) {
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+ 
    { 
        $refs = array(); 
        foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
        return $refs; 
    } 
    return $arr; 
}
```